# Handshake failed android

Tags: java, android

Buenas compañeros me parece que esta respuesta ya ah sido publicada pero no entiendo bien como aplicarla en mi código, estoy realizando una prueba para hacer una conexión a una BD remota, sin embargo al momento tratar de guardar me sale este error

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
javax.net.ssl.SSHandshakeException:
Handshake failed
```

Eh visto que esto se debe a protocolos o certificados, pero no entiendo como puedo aplicar alguna solución, les comparto mi código donde envió la información a la BD

```
private void EjecutarServicio(String URL) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Bitmap bitmap = foto.getDrawingCache();
                parametros.put("codigo",codigo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("nombre",nombre.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("precio",precio.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("foto",convertirImgString(bitmap));
                return parametros;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas Volley, asegura que la url que usas es https://:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

de otra forma, puedes temporalmente activar la compatibilidad "ClearText" para que te permita conexiones usando `http://`, esto se realiza dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

---

Si obtienes el error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR  al parecer es un error relacionado a el certificado.

Del lado de tu dispositivo prueba si la hora y fecha es correcta o si no estas bajo un firewall que podría provocar que se bloqueen las conexiones SSL / TSL.

De lado del servidor asegurar que el certificado es válido y esta correctamente instalado.

Comment: Hola mi url es https://:IP (sin los : despues de //) ya había revisado ese punto añadí la línea al manifest pero me sigue saliendo ese mismo mensaje

Comment: ups probablemente es https:// pero el certificado no es válido :-| has probado la petición usando otra herramienta como Postman?

Comment: También al cambiar la url de ```https://``` en el navegador me sale ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Si Luis, si obtienes el error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR  al parecer es un error relacionado a el certificado. Del lado de tu dispositivo prueba si la hora y fecha es correcta o si no estas bajo un firewall que podría provocar que se bloqueen las conexiones SSL / TSL.